# Eliminar TextShadow contorno de números en gráfica Highcharts JavaScript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estoy intentando eliminar el contorno blanco de los números en cada columna y agregar separador de miles en estos mismos números.

Me podrían ayudar indicandome como hacerlo.

Muchas gracias.

```js
var contador = 0;
var contador2 = 0;
var arreglo = [];
Highcharts.chart('resumencontainer', {
  colors: ['#01579B', '#FFFF00', '#006064'],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Ingreso'
  },
  subtitle: {},
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Empresa'],
    title: {
      text: null
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Toneladas',
      align: 'high'
    },
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' Tons'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        borderRadius: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#BDBDBD',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#AAA',
        y: -6
      }
    },
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          var color = 'Black';
          if (this.series.name == "Cuota Por Hora") {
            arreglo[contador] = this.y;
            contador = contador + 1;
          }
          if (this.series.name == "Cuota Ingresada") {
            var meta = arreglo[contador2];
            var cuota = this.y;
            if (cuota > meta) {
              color = 'green';
            } else if (cuota < meta / 100 * 80) {
              color = 'red';
            } else if (cuota < meta) {
              color = '#FFD600';
            }
            contador2 = contador2 + 1;
          }
          return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2,'.',',') + ' </span>';
        },
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -40,
    y: 50,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#ECEFF1'),
    shadow: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Meta Del Día',
    data: [13900.00]
  }, {
    name: 'Cuota Por Hora',
    data: [2316.67]
  }, {
    name: 'Cuota Ingresada',
    data: [2049.75]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="resumencontainer" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Puede que te ayude esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657476/format-amount-field-with-comma-and-decimal/18657757#18657757

Comment: Gracias, solo pude lograrlo con Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2,'.',',') solo me falta eliminar el textshadow en los números.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré cambiar el formato de los números con:

```
Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2,'.',',');
```

Eliminar el TextShadow se puede eliminar de dos maneras, dependiendo la versión de la librería.

En versiones anteriores a la 5.0.3 se llama TextShadow

```
plotOptions: {
    columnrange: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'red',
            style: {
                textShadow: false 
            }
        }
    }
},
```

y en la versión 5.0.3 es TextOutline:

```
plotOptions: {
    columnrange: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'red',
            style: {
                textOutline: false 
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Aquí ya resuelto:

```js
var contador = 0;
var contador2 = 0;
var arreglo = [];
Highcharts.chart('resumencontainer', {
  colors: ['#01579B', '#FFFF00', '#006064'],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Ingreso'
  },
  subtitle: {},
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Empresa'],
    title: {
      text: null
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Toneladas',
      align: 'high'
    },
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' Tons'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        borderRadius: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#BDBDBD',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#AAA',
        y: -6
      }
    },
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
         style: {
                    textOutline: false 
                },
        formatter: function() {
          var color = 'Black';
          if (this.series.name == "Cuota Por Hora") {
            arreglo[contador] = this.y;
            contador = contador + 1;
          }
          if (this.series.name == "Cuota Ingresada") {
            var meta = arreglo[contador2];
            var cuota = this.y;
            if (cuota > meta) {
              color = 'green';
            } else if (cuota < meta / 100 * 80) {
              color = 'red';
            } else if (cuota < meta) {
              color = '#FFD600';
            }
            contador2 = contador2 + 1;
          }
          return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2,'.',',') + ' </span>';
        },
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -40,
    y: 50,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#ECEFF1'),
    shadow: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Meta Del Día',
    data: [13900.00]
  }, {
    name: 'Cuota Por Hora',
    data: [2316.67]
  }, {
    name: 'Cuota Ingresada',
    data: [2049.75]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="resumencontainer" style="height: 300px"></div>
```